# Error 927 while updating YouTube

Tags: google-play-store, updates, youtube

I am suddenly getting Error 927 while updating the YouTube App from Official Google Play Store on my Android device.

Android version: 4.2 and Device name: Micromax Canvas 4

I am using 2G Internet connection and  the network coverage is sub-optimal. I am using the same device since last 2 years and never saw this issue in past. Also, this issue I am seeing coming only for Updating YouTube App.

For other App's update, there is no problem.

**EDIT: When I tried updating YouTube App using Wi-Fi it worked!! So it seems like Network issue**

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1 :**

Go to `Settings -> Applications` and find Google Play. Then > `Clear Cache`.

or

**Method 2 :**

Go to `Settings > Accounts > Google and remove your google account`. Then add it back to the device and ***try redownload*** or ***reupdate*** the App. If it doesn't work and the error is still there give it some time. It'll likely clear itself out and you'll be able to download the App later.

Sources and other Links :

[Error 927 Google Play](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2211613) (Xda forum)

[Error 927 Google playstore](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/358438-error-927-google-playstore.html) (androidcentral)

[Android Fix: Error 927 while downloading or updating apps in Google Play Store](http://appslova.com/android-fix-error-927-while-downloading-or-updating-apps-in-google-play-store/)

[Different Ways To Get Rid Of Error 927 In Android](http://techlogitic.com/different-ways-get-rid-error-927-android/)

Comment: Thanks for answer but these tips don't quite solved the issue. Now, when I updated YouTube using Wi-Fi there is no error 927! Seems like some Network issue

Comment: So, This is about your network.just try it with another Ip or something like Filter Crusher.hope this fix.and also, check `Etc/Hosts` for blocking or unblocking ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Accounts > Google and remove your google account. Then add it back to the device and try redownload or reupdate the App.

Also Check for Phone Memory it might be full due to unwanted applications installed.

Source :- [Fix Error 927](http://techlogitic.com/different-ways-get-rid-error-927-android/)